# Insert newline between lower and uppercase letters

Tags: sed

Whenever there is a lowercase followed by an uppercase I want a newline between both.

```
sed 's/[a-z][A-Z]/$1\n$2/g' test > test2
```

Comment: Ok... and your question is...?

Comment: How would it be the sed command to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
sed -E 's/([a-z])([A-Z])/\1\n\2/g'
```

Just two changes were needed:

- The back-references are done with backslashes, like `\1`, not dollar signs.
- To enable the back-references, the letters need to inside parens.  I added the `-E` flag for *extended regular expressions* (ERE), so that we didn't need to escape the parens.

For example:

```
$ echo aZZaB | sed -E 's/([a-z])([A-Z])/\1\n\2/g'
a
ZZa
B
```

#### Improvement

`a-z` and `A-Z` are not unicode-safe.  It is more reliable to use the appropriate character classes:

```
sed -E 's/([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])/\1\n\2/g'
```

#### Alternative

If we don't use `-E`, then sed defaults to *basic regular expressions* (BRE).   We can use BRE but we need to escape the parens like this:

```
sed 's/\([[:lower:]]\)\([[:upper:]]\)/\1\n\2/g'
```